# Why can't we divide the electromagnetic spectrum into arbitrarily many radio frequency bands?

Tags: rf, wireless, radio, cellphone, frequency-modulation

I understand there is concern over the limited amount of wireless spectrum available for allocation but am somewhat confused as to why. Couldn't we just divide the electromagnetic spectrum into as many radio frequency bands as we need by making the communication frequency more precise, i.e. broadcasting over 101.713 MHz instead of 101.7 MHz in order to make more room. What are the limiting factors preventing us from doing this?

Comment: Do a web search on "channel capacity".  There's a strong correlation on occupied bandwidth and data rate -- and the more channels you shove into a given bandwidth, of necessity the narrower those channels need to be.

Comment: @TimWescott Thanks, that is exactly the information I was looking for but couldn't find the name.

Comment: It's kind of like trying to make more room in a box by dividing it up into arbitrarily small compartments. The compartments get less useful because each one can hold less and less.

Comment: Information is carried along in SIDEBANDS.  To preserve the information, the sidebands need substantial energy and cannot be arbitrarily filtered.

Comment: This is actually where the term _bandwidth_ comes from - the band needs some width. Put overy simply, the more (band)width the more information you can reliably transmit over said band. Hence the _less_ (band)width, the less information, until the band gets too narrow to be of any use.

Comment: I think this is a great question when you're new to RF. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signals don't exist at a single frequency. They have a bandwidth that spreads across spectrum. The radio station at 101.7MHz takes up the spectrum from 101.6-101.8MHz.